# Why v2 is not the default reader/writer for parquet

Tags: apache-spark

even in spark 3.5 `spark.sql.sources.useV1SourceList=avro,csv,json,kafka,orc,parquet,text` is there a reason that though v2 should only have advantages over v1 it's still not being used by default

Comment: You can set it to use V2 using: `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.writer.version", "v1") // either "v1" or "v2"`

Comment: That's wasn't the question